# Regarding the Floyd-Warshall algorithm's O(n^2) storage

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science-theory

Why is storage [image]  in the Floyd-Warshall algorithm?  Wouldn't it be less than that if a linked-list was used as opposed to an N by N matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worst-case size of that linked list would still be `O(n^2)` (I think? I'm not entirely sure I understand how you propose to use it), but the lookup cost would be sufficiently expensive to change the asymptotic complexity of the overall algorithm (operations on linked lists do not have the same complexity as operations on matrices of known size).

Comment: my proposal for a linked list would be each node would be representative of a vertex in the graph.  This way you would only be storing the number of vertices in the graph v+e times as opposed to v^2 times.  My algorithms professor said it is often better to store a graph as a linked list than as an N by N matrix, but my argument was that the lookup cost would be too expensive as opposed to the space saved.  Her argument was that if you have a billion vertices, then the space saved would be worth it.  I'm thinking this is not true though.

Comment: A linked list is rather wacky way to store a graph.  Do you mean storing an adjacency list?  That's rather different.  Keep in mind that you still need somewhere to store all the weights, which in the worst case is `(n-1)^2` values.